# Matlab grid creation basics

Tags: matlab

I have a vector:

```
theta = 0.1:0.001:1
```

And i have a function:

```
kstar=((1/beta-(1-delta))/(A*theta))^(1/(theta-1))
```

the parameter values are:
    beta=0.96;
    delta=0.05;

how do i create another vector kstarnew with each element reflecting the corresponding theta in the theta vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify `kstar` to use elementwise operations, e.g. `.*` instead of `*`

Comment: Daniel, i did try that, do I have to do it for every division sign and multiplcation sign?

Comment: Daniel my previous comment turned out to be accurate. thanks for this answer i got it working